# XML serialization of objects through Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

My idea -> client server system, exchanges text messages (strings) through TCP sockets. I want the protocol between client and server to be based on XML. And because information between sockets is sent as `byte`, I have to cast. So here is what I do:
Class `TheMessage` with property of type `string`. I make object of that class with the string to be sent as property of the object, and make it from `Object` to `byte[]` through `XmlSerialization`. On the other side I do the vise-versa process. 
*This is how I serialize and send from the client to the server:*

```
msg.Message = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] writeBuff = XmlRefacrotClient.ObjectToByteArray(msg);
Stream stm = client.GetStream();
stm.Write(writeBuff, 0, writeBuff.Length);
```

*this is the method I use for serialization:*

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(TheMessage obj)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message.TheMessage));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTW = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

        xmlS.Serialize(xmlTW, obj);
        ms = (MemoryStream)xmlTW.BaseStream;

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

*this is how I receive the data on the server side:*

```
byte[] readBuff = new byte[1024];
s.Receive(readBuff);
String str = (XmlRefactorServer.ByteArrayToObject(readBuff)).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

*and this is the method for de-serialization:*

```
public static Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arr)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message.TheMessage));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTW = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

        return xmlS.Deserialize(ms);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Everything runs smooth until the `return` of `ByteArrayToObject` method.I get `InvalidOperationException` with description `There is an error in XML document (0, 0).` on the `return xmlS.Deserialize(ms);` line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you taken the byte array and converted it into a string or something, to see what it looks like? Perhaps you can spot the error in the XML if you see what it looks like.

Comment: I first did it only by converting string -> byte array -> string (to test the connection itself) and it was working fine. I was receiving and sending messages in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's a lot cleaner:

```
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static Byte[] ObjectToByteArray<T>(T obj)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                xmlS.Serialize(ms, obj);

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static T ByteArrayObject<T>(Byte[] bObj)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bObj))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheMessage));
                return (T)xmlS.Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void Sending(Byte[] bData)
        {
            Stream stm = client.GetStream();

            // always write size first when using TCP
            Byte[] bSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(bData.Length);
            stm.Write(bSize, 0, bSize.Length);
            stm.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void Receiving(Byte[] bData)
        {
            Byte[] bSize = new Byte[sizeof(Int32)];
            s.Read(bSize, 0, bSize.Length);

            Byte[] bData = new Byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(bSize, 0)];
            s.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);

            TheMessage m = ByteArrayObject<TheMessage>(bData);
        }
```

Comment: Okey, this works now. With the exception that in `Receiving()` you wrote `s.Read()` and `Read()` is a method of `NetworkStream` not `Socket`, but I created a `NetworkStream(s)`, so it's fine. 

I transfer data without getting errors, but I don't get the text visualized. I see that whenever I send smth from the client - the cursor on the server console window goes one line down, but no text visualized. That should be because I currently don't have any data as `String` to write to the console, so it's just making new lines. So probably I don't get any information at all... ?